# Parameter index out of range with Multiple Join and Optional input parameter

Tags: mysql, jdbctemplate

I have an issue with the multiple Join using Spring JdbcTemplate if I need to make optional the input parameters.

This is the scenario.

The SQL table where i must perform the Join are:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id             INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name           VARCHAR(15),
password       VARCHAR(20),
info           VARCHAR(30),
active         BOOLEAN,
locked         BOOLEAN,
lockout_duration INT DEFAULT 0,
lockout_limit  DATETIME,
login_attempts INT DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE profiles (
id             INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name           VARCHAR(15),
info           VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE profiling(
user_id        INT NOT NULL,
profile_id     INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(user_id,profile_id)
);
```

Where profiling is the table to associate a user with his profile; the profile must be intended as the identification of what actions are permitted to users.

In one my precedent post, i ask how to make optional the sql parameters and I obtained a perfect response, that works and i have always used since then. So, if i need to make this, is put in the where:

WHERE (is null or variabile_name = ?)

And, using jdbctemplate, i write:

jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new Object[]{variabile_name, variabile_name}, mapper_name);

where, of course, SQL is the String object where i make the Query.

So, i make this also in this case, but i got the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
```

I report the full method here:

```
/**
     * This metod return the join between users and profiles
     * made using the profiling table
     * 
     * @param userID the user id code
     * @param profilesID the profile id code
     * @return the join list
     */
    public List<Profiling> joinWithUsersandProfiles(Integer userID, Integer profileID)
    {
        //This is the mapper for Profiling
        RowMapper<Profiling> profilingMapper = new RowMapper<Profiling>()
        {
            //This method must be implemented when we use a row mapper
            public Profiling mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
            {
                Profiling profiling = new Profiling();
                profiling.setUser_id(rs.getInt("profiling.user_id"));
                profiling.setProfile_id(rs.getInt("profiling.profile_id"));
                //mapping users variabiles
                profiling.setUsersId(rs.getInt("users.id"));
                profiling.setUsersActive(rs.getBoolean("users.active"));
                profiling.setUsersInfo(rs.getString("users.info"));
                profiling.setUsersLocked(rs.getBoolean("users.locked"));
                profiling.setUsersLockoutDuration(rs.getInt("users.lockout_duration"));
                profiling.setUsersLockoutLimit(rs.getTime("users.lockout_limit"));
                profiling.setUsersLoginAttempts(rs.getInt("users.login_attempts"));
                profiling.setUsersName(rs.getString("users.name"));
                profiling.setUsersPassword(rs.getString("users.password"));
                //mapping profiles variabiles
                profiling.setProfilesId(rs.getInt("profiles.id"));
                profiling.setProfilesInfo(rs.getString("profiles.info"));
                profiling.setProfilesName(rs.getString("profiles.name"));

                return profiling;

            }
        };

        /**
         * This is the string that contain the query to obtain the data from profiling table.
         * Please note that the notation "? is null or x = ?" means that the x variabile is optional;
         * it can be asked as no making the query. 
         * If we give alla input equals null, it means that we must perform a SQl Select * From table.
         */
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM profiling JOIN users ON profiling.user_id = users.id JOIN profiles ON profiling.profile_id = profiles.id WHERE (is null or profiling.user_id = ?) AND (is null or profiling.profile_id = ?)";

        /**
         * The list containing the results is obtained using the method query on jdcbtemplate, giving in in input to it the query string, the array of object 
         * containing the input variabile of the method and the rowmapper implemented.
         */
        List<Profiling> theProfilings = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new Object[]{userID, userID, profileID, profileID}, profilingMapper); 

        return theProfilings;
    }
```

I know that the problem is made by the optional variabile. Why? if i try to remove the optional code and pass from:

```
(is null or variabile_name = ?)
```

to

```
variabile_name = ?
```

The code work perfectly.

So, what's my error here?

Edit: solved myself. I forgot the ? BEFORE the "is null" code. So, passing to:

```
(? is null or variabile_name = ?)
```

The code works.